# Aggregation with order by integer

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to make an aggregation and sort the results by an integer field.
I know how to do with type string, but not with integer.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "municipios": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "doenca",
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ages": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "age",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "order": { ? ? ? ? },
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do you sort the result in least to greatest order (ascending)?

Comment: you have to order by _term (the field) or the metric like _count like this example                 "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }

Comment: Could you provide sample input and desired output?

Comment: hello waldemar,
I tried your solution, and it worked.
  I had tried previously, this solution using the "_term" and had not worked, but now he is returning properly.

Comment: `"size": 0` within an aggregation means that it will fetch _all_ results, not just the top N. "All" does not scale.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting against the special `_term` key in `asc` order was what was needed to make this work.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "municipios": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "doenca",
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ages": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "age",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            },
          "size": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```